# cms in ASP.NET/MVC literature

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I got my theme for "graduate work" (I dont know if this is the right term but I think you'll understand :)) which is: **Developing CMS in ASP.NET/MVC** 
What I need is some good literature and if someone could recommend something I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002JMV6RI)

[image: Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0]

It has The Gu!

Comment: Also, the first chapter is available for free: http://tinyurl.com/aspnetmvc which walks you through creating the Nerd Dinner site.

Answer (score 3):

[N2](http://n2cms.com) has documentation and a recently [active lead developer](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/smason) working on an lightweight CMS framework implementation in [asp.net-mvc](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29374).

Comment: Yep, I've recently deployed a couple of sites using the MVC Example site from N2 - great product, lots of fast support.